# Cannot get text of element with Selenium

Tags: python, css, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I have the DOM element below:

```
<span class="styles__Content-rlm06o-1 ixoRjG">20.00000000</span>
```

that  I am trying to get the `20.00000000` value from with:

```
text = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@class='styles__Content-rlm06o-1 ixoRjG']")[0].text
...
number = float(text)
```

But Python returns back `could not convert string to float: ''` meaning that the `20.00000000` is not being recognized as text. This code has worked on other websites, so maybe this is a website specific thing? Or is there something I'm overlooking?

Comment: The string is empty (`''`). This cannot be casted to float. (Try `print(text)`)

Comment: Are you sure that is the first element with those classes?

Comment: @Sven Eberth Yea I know. The problem is that `20.00000000` is not being recognized as a string. `print(text)` just prints an empty line as a result.

Comment: @JohnGordon Element inspector says it's 1 of 16.

Comment: @JohnGordon The element represents a summary for an account balance on the website primedice.com and is always the first element of its kind on the DOM. It's a basic element that also exists on its sister website (stake.com) which I can interact with with the same code with no issues. Here's a [visual](https://i.imgur.com/dxFSDHv.png) to help.

Comment: I didn't mean the content of the element; I meant something like getting its xpath to help understand why the `find_elements_by_xpath()` function found that element instead of the one you wanted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to get the text of the first element with this XPath expression:

```
el_text = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[contains(@class, 'styles__Content-rlm06o-1 ixoRjG')][1]").text
```

Also, you can use CSS selectors with way:

```
el_text = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".styles__Content-rlm06o-1.ixoRjG:nth-of-type(1)").text
```

If the text is still empty, make sure you are waiting for the element to become visible and that this element is not inside an iframe.

Comment: First suggestion worked. Thanks! Still have no idea why selecting the class in this way makes a difference though.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably getting a different element from that list. I suggest a similar approach as proposed [by vitaliis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67854818/cannot-get-text-of-element-with-selenium/67855181#67855181), but instead of looking by class, look by text.

```
text = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[contains(text(), '20')]").text
number = float(text)
print(number)
```

Comment: It will only work if text value is always the same.

Comment: well, yes, but in not explicit in the question that you want to extract from multiple nodes
anyway, you need to certify that your xpath is directing to the right element, one way to check that is to build a `for` loop and print the text of each occurence of that class name.

Comment: As I see, `that I am trying to get the 20.00000000 value from with:` explicitly says that asker wants to get a value. I understand what you mean, but what is required here is just to get a unique locator. A value can start not only with 20, but can be different, as I see it.